# how to reload python's module?

Tags: python

I'm implementing the following method in python:

```
def install_s3cmd():
    subprocess.call(['sudo easy_install s3cmd'])

    # assuming that by now it's already been installed
    import pexpect

    # now use pexpect to configure s3cdm
    child = pexpect.spawn('s3cmd --configure')
    child.expect ('(?i)Access Key')
    # ... more code down there

def main():
    subprocess.call(['sudo apt-get install python-setuptools']) # installs easy_install
    subprocess.call(['sudo easy_install pexpect']) # installs pexpect
    install_s3cmd()
    # ... more code down here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I need to have `pexpect` installed, so I can install `s3cmd --configure`. `pexpect` is installed correctly, and in the first time the script is executed, I get an error saying it could find `pexpect`. However, the second time I run the script it work flawless. It's probably because python libraries hasn't been updated. How can I refresh, or update the python's module so I don't have that problem again?

Comment: incidentally: rather than shelling out to sudo (!), you might want to just write a `setup.py` for this script and let a tool like pip install the dependencies for you.

Comment: @Eevee I will do that eventually

Answer (score 2):

When Python starts up, it figures out which directories to search for modules, and adds them all to `sys.path`.  The problem you're seeing is probably because apt installs a whole new directory, which Python then doesn't know about.

I can't say how reliable this is, but there are functions in the [`site` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) that claim to do the same directory scanning as Python does on startup, so you could try this:

```
import site
import sys
sys.path[:] = site.getusersitepackages() + site.getsitepackages()
```

Caveats: this will *not* leave the current directory in your path, it might confuse existing modules if the directories have changed a lot since the program started, etc.

A slightly more robust approach would be to check through the lists returned by those functions and add any *new* directories to the end of `sys.path`, rather than replace it outright.

Comment: `local variable 'pexpect' referenced before assignment` ... that's what happened

Comment: perhaps you need to post more of your code; that shouldn't happen given what's in your question.